# How to add vm option to jetty?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, javaagents

How it is available to specify vm option like **-javaagent** to start jetty or it is available only thru MAVEN_OPTS variable? I need it to enable load-time-weaving of aspects. This plugin seems like doesn't work.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>maven</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-javaagent:path\to\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.6.10\aspectjweaver-1.6.10.jar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

May be it can be done by jetty-plugin, but its tag systemProperties said that

> will NOT override System properties that have been 
>    set on the command line or by the JVM

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

you can try add something like this 
-javaagent:%PATH_TO_AGENT%\spring-agent-2.5.6.jar
to the JAVA_OPTS

Comment: hm, ok... You can try to use **exec-maven-plugin** for set VM arguments. Other alternative - use **MAVEN_OPTS** (but it also system-wide- but only for maven )